# How to autoplay video without sound?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like my video to start playing automatically when the page is launched without sound just like on this page:  https://getreact.io/mobile-01/.

I've tried any possible jQuery/javascript/CSS option I could find online but I always end up with Google error that's blocking the video from autoplay unless there was an interaction.

How did they do it in the link above?

Comment: Add the `muted` attribute to the video. As per MDN: `In some browsers (e.g. Chrome 70.0) autoplay doesn't work if no muted attribute is present.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: how can i mute the video on this page tho : https://ishop-gadget.com/products/the-new-affordable-smart-watch

Comment: add the `muted` attribute to the `video` element, as described above

Comment: $("video").prop('muted', true); //mute
it mutes the video but still no auto play

Comment: solved using this : video.defaultMuted = true;

Answer (score 2):

In order to give users control over this, browsers often provide various forms of autoplay blocking. Browser's autoplay blocking policy is not applied to media elements when the source media does not have an audio track, or if the audio track is muted.

For eg: The browser Chrome maintains a `Media Engagement Index` which represents an individual's tendency to play/consume media on a site. You could check it by visiting `chrome://media-engagement`.

The content can be autoplayed in various ways:

1. Attempt autoplay on mute mode always. Could be achieved in the following ways:

- Add `autoplay` and `muted` attributes in the media tag.
  `<video controls width="250" autoplay muted>`
- `defaultMuted` property could be used for this, which indicates whether the media element's audio output should be muted by default. (NOTE: The support for `defaultMuted` on IE is unknown.)
- `muted` property could also be accessed directly and switched on before invoking the play action. This could be done as follows:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video')

if (video.play() !== undefined) {
  video.muted = true
  video.play().then(_ => {
    // Muted autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented due to some error.
  });
}
```

2. Attempt autoplay with audio and show the play button if autoplay action is rejected by the browser. This can be achieved by adding `autoplay` attribute to the media tag or by simply invoking `.play()` on the media element. On rejection the play button could be shown. The successful play would depend upon various forms of autoplay blocking done by the browser.

```
var video = document.querySelector('video')

if (video.play() !== undefined) {
  video.play().then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started with audio!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented by browser.
    // Show play button
  });
}
```

3. Attempt autoplay with the audio or play on mute mode if the browser rejects autoplay with audio. You can try playing the content first, which if not successful, play the media as muted, if it is still rejected, show the play button, and wait for user action.

```
var video = document.querySelector('video')

if (video.play() !== undefined) {
  video.play().then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Try muted autoplay
    video.muted = true
    video.play().then(_ => {
      // Muted autoplay started. Show unmute button
    }).catch(error => {
        // Autoplay was prevented.
        // Show a "Play" button so that the user can start playback.
    })
  });
}
```

For chrome, if the MEI of a user for a website is low, chrome does not allow autoplay, however, the content could be autoplay if in muted mode and the user has the option to chose to unmute.

[Chrome autoplay policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Comment: how can i mute a video on shopify tho... i used your code and still doesn't work : 
https://ishop-gadget.com/products/the-new-affordable-smart-watch

Comment: Even for `shopify`, video is an HTML tag. Please extract the HTML media element using javascript and play the video. You would have to trigger the play event on document ready or whenever your video element is injected in DOM.
On this page, once your video element is loaded extract it using the `querySelector` and then play the video using the promise exposed by. HTML video element. If rejected set `muted` property as `true`, as shown in the function above and try playing the video again.

Comment: solved the problem using this : video.defaultMuted = true;

Comment: You basically had to retry playing the video after muting.
NOTE: defaultMuted would play the video muted at all times, even though the browser would have allowed the video to be played with audio.

Answer (score 0):

try this only html it posible

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The video muted attribute</h1>

<video width="320" height="240" controls muted>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```